# Copiar um option selecionada de uma select multiple para outra select multiple com jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select, html-option, selecteditem

Quero copiar uma `option` ou mais option's selecionadas de uma `select` `multiple` para outra `select` `multiple` com jquery.

```
<select id='cursos' multiple>
<option selected>curso 1</option>
<option selected>curso 2</option>
<option>curso 3</option>
<option>curso 4</option>
</select>


<select id='cursosrealizados' multiple>
<option>curso 1</option>
<option>curso 2</option>
</select>
```

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia ou sugestão agradeço.

Comment: Fica um pouco complicado se os elementos não tem referencia, class, value ou id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão de implementação

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8us55czu/2/)**

Se deseja copiar ao carregar a página

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cursosrealizados').html('');//limpa cursos realizados
    //faz loop pelas opcoes selecionads no select de cursos
    $('#cursos option:selected').each(function() {
       //clona a opcao selecionada
       var opt = $(this).clone(true).prop('selected',true);
       //coloca no select de cursos realizados
       $('#cursosrealizados').append(opt);
    });
});
```

Se você deseja copiar ao selecionar

```
$('#cursos').on('change', function(){
    $('#cursosrealizados').html('');//limpa cursos realizados
    //faz loop pelas opcoes selecionads no select de cursos
    $('#cursos option:selected').each(function() {
       //clona a opcao selecionada
       var opt = $(this).clone(true).prop('selected',true);
       //coloca no select de cursos realizados
       $('#cursosrealizados').append(opt);
    });
});
```

Comment: Faltou jQuery no seu código :) Só adicionaria um `disabled` no #cursosrealizado... Super elegante ++1

Answer (score 1):

Acabei utilizando desta forma, tem base na sua resposta, só resolvi tentar simplificar:

```
$("#cursos option:selected" ).each(function() {  
    $("#cursosrealizados").append("<option>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
});
```