# Função não está retirando os dados!

Tags: javascript, html

```js
//INSERIR
function move_patr_seri(Origem, Destino)
{
  var w_Cont_Qtde = 0;
  var w_Qtde_Peri = 4;
  var v_patr = new Array();

 var w_valor = Origem.value;
 var w_tipo;
    w_tipo = "S";
      

 if(Origem.name == "tx_patr")
     {
  w_tipo = "P";
     }
     
 if (w_Cont_Qtde <=  w_Qtde_Peri - 1)
       {
  if ((v_patr.indexOf(w_tipo+w_valor) == -1) && (w_valor != ""))
  {
   var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
   opt.text = w_valor ;
   opt.value = w_valor ;
   Destino.options.add(opt);
   //Cria o Vetor
   v_patr[w_Cont_Qtde] = w_tipo + w_valor;    
   w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde + 1;
   if (Origem.name == "tx_patr"){ document.forms['sai_frm_incl_patr_seri'].tx_patr.focus();}
   else { document.forms['sai_frm_incl_patr_seri'].tx_seri.focus(); }  
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
      alert("Patrimônio OU Serial já existe OU não é válido!");
   return true;
  }
   }

 else
 if(w_ver == 1){
  alert("Quantidade atingida!");
  if(confirm("Deseja inserir a mesma quantidade para ambos?") == true)
  {
   w_cont = w_Qtde_Peri;
   w_ver = 0;
   w_Qtde_Peri = w_Qtde_Peri + w_Qtde_Peri;
   return true;
  }
 }
 else
  alert("Quantidade informada ja Incluida !!!");
   return true; 
}
function tira(Destino)
{
 var w_letra;
 var w_tira;
 w_letra = "S";
 if (Destino.name == "cb_Patr"){
   w_letra = "P";  
  }
   
 var i;
 for(i = 0; i < Destino.options.length; i++)
 { 
  if (Destino.options[i].selected && Destino.options[i].value != "")
  {
   w_tira = w_letra+Destino.options[i].value;
   
   v_patr.splice(v_patr.indexOf(w_tira), 1);  
   w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde - 1;      
   Destino.remove(Destino.selectedIndex);
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="sai_frm_incl_patr_seri" method="post" >
 <body> 
      <table>
        <tr>
  <td>   
     <font face="arial" align="center" valign="middle" color="blue" size="-1">PATRIMÔNIO</font><br>
      <input type="text" name="tx_patr" id="id_patr" maxlength="12" size="12" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event);" onkeyup="Mascara(this,Patri);" value="">
      <input type="button" onClick="move_patr_seri(this.form.tx_patr,this.form.cb_Patr);limpa_patr();" value=">>">
     <br>
     <select multiple size="7" name="cb_Patr" style="width:300">
       </select>     
     <br>
      <input type="button" align="center" valign="middle" onClick="tira(this.form.cb_Patr)" value="<<">
     <br>
    </td>     
   </tr>
  </table><br>


 </body> 
</form>
```

Eu tenho um trecho de código que o usuário insere dados em uma box e pode retirar se assim desejar. Assim essa foi a parte de inclusão. Agora estou na parte de **"alteração"** que basicamente é o mesmo código, onde eu só populo a box com os dados que o usuário digitou e ele ve se quer retirar ou inserir mais dados. Mas, a função não está retirando os dados que está mostrando. **Código:**

**HTML**

```
    <td>   
        <font face="arial" align="center" valign="middle" color="blue" size="-1">PATRIMÔNIO</font><br>
            <input type="text" name="tx_patr" id="id_patr" maxlength="12" size="12" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event);" onkeyup="Mascara(this,Patri);" value="">
            <input type="button" onClick="move_patr_seri(this.form.tx_patr,this.form.cb_Patr);limpa_patr();" value=">>">
        <br>
            <select multiple size="7" name="cb_Patr" style="width:300">
                <?
                $w_querybusca="$w_select;";    
                $w_queryresultado=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);    

                while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresultado))
                {
                    print('<option value="'.$w_registro->tx_num_patr.'">'.trim($w_registro->tx_num_patr).'</option>'."\n");
                }
                ?>
           </select>                    
        <br>
            <input type="button" align="center" valign="middle" onClick="tira(this.form.cb_Patr)" value="<<">
        <br>
    </td>
```

Nesse trecho eu tenho a box e os botões para incluir e retirar na box!

[image: HTML]

**JS**

```
//RETIRAR 
function tira(Destino)
{
    var w_letra;
    w_letra = "S";
    if (Destino.name == "cb_Patr"){
            w_letra = "P";      
        }

    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < Destino.options.length; i++)
    { 
        if (Destino.options[i].selected && Destino.options[i].value != "")
        {
            w_tira = w_letra+Destino.options[i].value;
            v_patr.splice(v_patr.indexOf(w_tira), 1);       
            w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde - 1;                      
            Destino.remove(Destino.selectedIndex.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Essa é a `função` que retira os dados da `box`, onde `v_patr` contem os dados que ele informou na inclusão e o w_letra é acrescentado na frente do valor para assim retirar do v_patr também (pois nele é adicionado as letras antes).

O problema se encontra no `v_patr.splice(v_patr.indexOf(w_tira), 1);`, onde estou adicionando os dados nele assim:

```
<?php
$w_select ="SELECT *    FROM public.sai_cad_patr_seri WHERE 
                                        sai_cad_patr_seri.fk_seq_cara_peri = '$arr_w_param[17]'";
$w_querybusc = "$w_select;"; 
$w_queryresult=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusc);
$index = 0;
$patr = array();
$seri = array();        
while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresult))
{
    $patr[$index] = "P".trim($w_registro->tx_num_patr);
    $seri[$index] = "S".trim($w_registro->tx_num_seri);
    $index++;
}
$string_patr = implode(",", $patr);
$string_seri = implode(",", $seri);
    print("<SCRIPT language=javascript> 

            v_patr = new Array (2); 

            v_patr = string_patr+','+ string_seri;

        </SCRIPT>");
?>
```

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo de como o HTML fica no browser?

Comment: E já agora o que pretende com `Destino.remove(Destino.selectedIndex);` ?

Comment: @Sergio, com esse trecho eu pretendo remover da combo o valor selecionado!

Comment: Ve se esse exemplo não te ajuda:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35184/copiar-um-option-selecionada-de-uma-select-multiple-para-outra-select-multiple-c

Comment: @DiegoSantos agradeço o exemplo, mas não entra nos "critérios da empresa", meio que não gostam de JQuery!

Comment: @Sergio, quanto a função `Destino.remove(Destino.selectedIndex.value);` ele pega o valor da combo e retira dela! Mas o retorno que ela está dando é undefinid! Oque seria?

Comment: Você poderia colocar teu código de forma [Executável](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2115/apresentando-js-css-e-html-execut%C3%A1veis?cb=1) aqui no SO.pt ou no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) pra gente ter como trabalhar em cima dele?

Comment: Claro @KaduAmaral

Comment: @KaduAmaral o executável dele não funciona pois ele pega variáveis do php e utiliza junto ao JS!

Comment: Então @Felipe, é só executar ai no teu projeto e copiar o código fonte gerado...

Comment: pronto @KaduAmaral editei para que funcionasse de acordo de como estou fazendo!

Comment: E como podem ver ele não retira os dados!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está declarando suas variáveis dentro da função:

```
function move_patr_seri(Origem, Destino)
{
  var w_Cont_Qtde = 0;
  var w_Qtde_Peri = 4;
  var v_patr = new Array();

  var w_valor = Origem.value;
  var w_tipo;
```

Assim toda vez que a função é chamada, é como se limpasse do *box* todos os itens, e na hora de remover não havia mais nenhum.

Para resolver, instancie suas variáveis no início do script.

```
<script>
   var v_patr = [];
   var w_Cont_Qtde = 0;
   var w_Qtde_Peri = 4;

   function move_patr_seri(Origem, Destino)
   {
      var w_valor = Origem.value;
      var w_tipo;
      w_tipo = (Origem.name == "tx_patr" ? "P" : "S") ;
```

---

## [Resultado](http://jsfiddle.net/d3u10hf3/)

---

```js
var Patri = '';
var v_patr = [];
var w_Cont_Qtde = 0;
var w_Qtde_Peri = 4;

// FIX
function SomenteNumero(){ return true;}
function limpa_patr(){return true;}
function Mascara(el, patri){return true;}

//INSERIR
function move_patr_seri(Origem, Destino) {

   var w_valor = Origem.value;
   var w_tipo;
    w_tipo = "S";
      

   if(Origem.name == "tx_patr")
       {
      w_tipo = "P";
       }
       
   if (w_Cont_Qtde <=  w_Qtde_Peri - 1)
       {
      if ((v_patr.indexOf(w_tipo+w_valor) == -1) && (w_valor != ""))
      {
         var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
         opt.text = w_valor ;
         opt.value = w_valor ;
         Destino.options.add(opt);
         //Cria o Vetor
         v_patr[w_Cont_Qtde] = w_tipo + w_valor;            
         w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde + 1;
         if (Origem.name == "tx_patr"){ document.forms['sai_frm_incl_patr_seri'].tx_patr.focus();}
         else { document.forms['sai_frm_incl_patr_seri'].tx_seri.focus();  }     
         Origem.value = '';
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
          alert("Patrimônio OU Serial já existe OU não é válido!");
          Origem.value = '';
         return true;
      }
     }

   else
   if(w_ver == 1){
      alert("Quantidade atingida!");
      if(confirm("Deseja inserir a mesma quantidade para ambos?") == true)
      {
         w_cont = w_Qtde_Peri;
         w_ver = 0;
         w_Qtde_Peri = w_Qtde_Peri + w_Qtde_Peri;
         Origem.value = '';
         return true;
      }
   }
   else
      alert("Quantidade informada ja Incluida !!!");
   return true; 
}

function tira(Destino) {
   var w_letra;
   var w_tira;
   w_letra = "S";
   if (Destino.name == "cb_Patr"){
         w_letra = "P";    
      }
   
   var i;
   for(i = 0; i < Destino.options.length; i++)
   { 
      if (Destino.options[i].selected && Destino.options[i].value != "")
      {
         w_tira = w_letra+Destino.options[i].value;
         
         v_patr.splice(v_patr.indexOf(w_tira), 1);    
         w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde - 1;                  
         Destino.remove(Destino.selectedIndex);
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<form name="sai_frm_incl_patr_seri" method="post">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <font face="arial" align="center" valign="middle" color="blue" size="-1">PATRIMÔNIO</font>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="tx_patr" id="id_patr" maxlength="12" size="12" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event);" onkeyup="Mascara(this,Patri);" value="">
            <input type="button" onClick="move_patr_seri(this.form.tx_patr,this.form.cb_Patr);limpa_patr();" value=">>">
            <br>
            <select multiple size="7" name="cb_Patr" style="width:300">
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="button" align="center" valign="middle" onClick="tira(this.form.cb_Patr)" value="<<">
            <br>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: eu não estou declarando as variaveis dentro da função! mais sim declaro elas no PHP! No executavel eu deixei elas dentro para mostrar como irão funcionar!

Comment: Então @Felipe, o problema que eu detectei foi esse, seu script está funcionando direitinho. Verifica o local que você está declarando as variáveis (tenta colocar no head) e verifica se está declarando com a palavra reservada `var`. Não sei se influência, mas veja se ela está no mesmo escopo das funções.

Comment: a parte que adicionei do php onde ele adiciona os valores em v_patr não influencia?

Comment: Se você estiver declarando a variável depois da função, ela não vai reconhecer sua variável global. @Felipe